# R users : how to uninstall a package installed with devtools::install_github("username/repo")

Tags: r, uninstallation

installed a package in R using devtools, ie 
devtools::install_github("username/repo_name")

how do I uninstall this package?

Comment: maybe check out `?remove.packages`

Comment: thanks.

I had uninstalled devtools and ?remove.packages wouldn't work when devtools was not installed.

novie|rusty me didn't realise I had to install a package after installing the package  with devtools.

Comment: `remove.packages` is from utils package. and if i am not wrong, `devtools::install_github` should install package directly into your libpath.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

my question was incomplete, I had not completed installation. 
.

```
devtools::install_github("username/repo_name")
install.packages("repo_name")
#package is now usable 
remove.packages("repo_name")
```

leaving this here in the hope others find it usable.